# DocuSign Recipient View gives URL to a signing session without host (In Person SIgning)

Tags: c#, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I am trying to create an In Person Signing session.

Following [this](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/send-envelope-to-in-person-signer/) example from the documentation, I am getting a URL from CreateRecipientView, that navigates me to a signing session, but without the prompt of a host or anything. It's the same behavior I get when I request a signature through e-mail, but there I don't need In Person Signing, so it's not an issue.

One difference between the example and my case is that I have to use a template instead, so I was trying to make TemplateRoles work instead in the EnvelopeDefinition.

Here is how my envelope definition and RecipientView is defined:

```cs
return new EnvelopeDefinition()
{
    TemplateId = templateId,
    EmailSubject = subject,
    Status = "Sent",

    TemplateRoles = new List<TemplateRole>
    {
        new TemplateRole()
        {
            Name = inPersonSignerHostName,
            Email = inPersonSignerHostEmail,
            InPersonSignerName = recipientName,
            ClientUserId = _authSettings.UserId,
            RoleName = "Customer",
            Tabs = SetTabValues(
                textTabs: recipientTextTabs
            )
        }
    }
};
```

```cs
RecipientViewRequest recipientViewRequest = new RecipientViewRequest()
{
    ReturnUrl = _authSettings.InPersonSignerReturnURL,
    AuthenticationMethod = "none",
    UserName = inPersonSignerHostName,
    Email = inPersonSignerHostEmail,
    ClientUserId = _authSettings.UserId
};
```

From what I have found, the `Email` and `Name` properties of the TemplateRole refer to the host's email and name in case of In Person Signing, and they have to match the recipient view's `UserName` and `Email` properties for it to work.

It is still not working, so I must be missing something. How do I get an actual In Person Signing session instead of a remote one? Currently the result looks exactly like a remote session I send by email.

**Update:**

As per Inbar Gazit's suggestion, I tested it without a template with the following Envelope definition, and I got the hosting request screen just fine.

```cs
return new EnvelopeDefinition()
            {
                //TemplateId = templateId,
                EmailSubject = subject,
                Status = "Sent",

                Documents = new List<Document>
                {
                    new Document
                    {
                        DocumentBase64 = "Base64 encoded document here",
                        Name = "Lorem Ipsum",
                        FileExtension = "pdf",
                        DocumentId = "1"
                    }
                },

                Recipients = new Recipients
                {
                    InPersonSigners = new List<InPersonSigner>
                    {
                        new InPersonSigner
                        {
                            HostName = inPersonSignerHostName,
                            Email = inPersonSignerHostEmail,
                            SignerName = recipientName,
                            RecipientId = "1",
                            RoutingOrder = "1",
                            Tabs = new Tabs {
                                SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>
                                {
                                    new SignHere
                                    {
                                        AnchorString = "/sn1/",
                                        AnchorUnits = "pixels",
                                        AnchorXOffset = "20",
                                        AnchorYOffset = "10"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            ClientUserId = _authSettings.UserId,
                            RoleName = "Customer"
                        }
                    }
                }

                /*
                TemplateRoles = new List<TemplateRole>
                {
                    new TemplateRole()
                    {
                        Name = inPersonSignerHostName,
                        Email = inPersonSignerHostEmail,
                        InPersonSignerName = recipientName,
                        ClientUserId = _authSettings.UserId,
                        RoleName = "Customer",
                        Tabs = SetTabValues(
                            textTabs: recipientTextTabs
                        )
                    }
                }
                */
            };
```

For the document I used the PDF sample mentioned in the documentation, encoded to Base64. For tabs I used the ones from the documentation as well.
The question then becomes, how do I make it work with templates?

Comment: Does it work for you w/o a template?

Comment: Can you do in person signing from the web app?

Comment: Hi! I tested it without a template, I got the hosting request screen this way. I will include the working definition without a template above. The question is then how to make this work with a template. Thank you for the fast  reply.

Comment: Does your template has an In Person Signer as one of the recipients?

Comment: The template has a role called "Customer" that is an In Person Signer?

Comment: @InbarGazit Yes, the template has an In Person Signer as it's one and only recipient. The role is also called "Customer" for this recipient.

Comment: I tried this yesterday and it worked ok using C# SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried it and it worked just fine.

Two things to confirm - the `roleName` must be identical to what is set in the template for the in-person signer.

Try to remove the `Tabs` element, try to remove the `clientUserId` element. These are just for testing to isolate any issues.

Comment: From what I can see, the roleName matches the one from the template. Tried omitting Tabs and clientUserId, this did not help either. I also found that the envelope being sent mentions the recipient as "Needs to sign" instead of "In Person Signer".

Comment: You should check your template. The template seems to me like it's not correct, or you're using the wrong template

Comment: Turns out that was the case. We are storing the templateId, and it was some other template which I can not even view with my account apparently. thank you so much for your help!